# Magento 2: How to get Product Id from Cart Item Id

Tags: magento2, cart, magento2.1.5

In Minicart, we have products

```
<input id="cart-602-qty" maxlength="12" name="cart[602][qty]" size="4" type="number">
```

This is not Product Id. So how to get actual product id from cart item id?

Lastly, can override template & put product id in hidden.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart 
) {
    $this->_cart = $cart;  
  }


public function getProductData()
{
    $productInfo = $this->_cart->getQuote()->getItemsCollection();
    //$productInfo = $this->_cart->getQuote()->getAllItems(); /*****For All items *****/
    foreach ($productInfo as $item){
       echo $item->getProductId();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is answer

```
$_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$productData = $_objectManager->get('Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item')->load(<item id>);
echo $productData->getProductId();
exit;
```

Comment: Direct use of an Object manager is not an appropriate answer.

Comment: I know. This is in general.

Comment: Then don't paste code like this or you should mention this in note. because new learner will post this code directly.

Answer (score 0):

Code for get added product in cart by the user in login or without login

## Note- If login then give current product quantity otherwise give overall  quantity

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
$context = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context');
$isLoggedIn = $context->getValue(\Magento\Customer\Model\Context::CONTEXT_AUTH);
$_product = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');
$itemsCollection = $cart->getQuote()->getItemsCollection();
foreach($itemsCollection->getData() as $item) 
{
       if($_product->getId()==$item['product_id'])
          { 
                if($isLoggedIn){
                  echo (int)$item['qty'];
                 }                                                                     
          }
}
```

Comment: How can I get $_product value?

Comment: @MuhammadMuizAther we have updated the code please check it again.
Hope it is working fine for you. If fine the please vote me

Answer (score 0):

If you have an cart item of the type `\Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartItemInterface` and you want to get the product ID you might find this useful:

```php
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepositoryInterface,
) {
    $this->productRepositoryInterface = $productRepositoryInterface;
}

public function someFunction(\Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartItemInterface $cartItem)
{
    $product = $this->productRepositoryInterface->get($cartItem->getSku());
    $productId = $product->getId();
    // ...
}
```

This function loads a product based on the SKU we can retrieve from the cart item.